# Automatically change current working directory to the location where I save the script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if I click run python file in terminal, the active script would be executed in the default working directory. What I want to do is automatically changing cwd to the location of the script I would like to run. I know I can use `cd` to manually change it, but it would become very annoying if I frequently switch between different scripts. So is there any easy way to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the debug configuration.

The python debugger supports the `cwd` attribute, and you probably want to set it to `${fileDirname}` - the current opened file's directory.

If you choose from the menu Debug / Open Configurations, it'll open a file called launch.json.

Here's my config with the `"cwd":"${fileDirname}"` attribute added.

`"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
     ]`

Reference:

Which variables are available:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Launch.json attributes: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes